# object size in Java

Tags: java, object

Suppose I have:

```
Class A{
   int a;
}

A obj = new A();
```

Then what will be size of obj? Will it be of same size as int size, like in C?

If I can figure out this, then I can keep large HashMap in RAM without using database.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Friends,

Actually I have:

```
HashMap<Long, List<T>> map;
```

and

```
class T{
   private int a;
   private int b;
   private int c;
   // constructor, getters and setters
}
```

And size of map may grow to have 10000000 keys and for each key I will have list of size 100-1000.

Will this whole map stay in heap?

**EDIT 2**

When I loaded map with around 70000 keys, and when I serialized it to file, file was of around 18 MB, so will my map be of 18 MB in heap?

Comment: Have you tried to print out the size of the object in a test program?

Comment: I believe that it is up to the JVM how much memory it needs for each instance of an object. You are still thinking too C-ish. Just trust the JVM.

Comment: @OdayMansour, how can I do sizeof in Java. That operator is in C only.

Comment: You could look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501328/java-memory-usage) - there are some nice answers on how java manages to allocate memory.

Comment: @Philipp, so will JVM can use any size? I will have huge HashMap, and I have fear of Hear Shortage.

Comment: It may depend on the VM. My experience was 12bytes + fields (int = 4 byte). You can try to measure it by create e.g. 10000 and ask the VM before and after how much memory is used.

Comment: Theoretically, the JVM could use some internal optimizations (like using copy-on-write or out-optimizing unnecessary variables) so that the size of some objects is even less than the sum of their members.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may depend on JVM, but in practice, for 32-bit JVM, an object = `8-byte header + fields`. Header consist of Id + reference to class.

Fields size depends on field type, reference - 8 bytes, boolean - 1 byte, etc

Besides objects are aligned to 8 bytes. That is your A takes 16 bytes. Minimum size = 8 bytes, no fields.

More here http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml

If you use Oracle JVM you can use sun.misc.Unsafe to investigate object structure, byte by byte.

Comment: @Evgeniy, will it be possible to keep whole hashmap in heap, as I have said in edit?

Comment: @user1508907 I think it's more than in the file. Open HashMap source. K+V is stored in Entry, K(Long) 16 bytes; T -  24; Entry - 24; total - 64 bytes per entry (K,V)

Answer (score 0):

No. It can never be of the same size as that in C because an object is created on heap whereas a reference variable is created on Stack. So therefore, it won't be of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

it will be size of the Object plus size of the int , because of your private member.

"I can keep large HashMap in RAM without using database" just need to deal with persistentce: serialization and deserialization, and as Object stream it is be to much.

Answer (score 0):

64 bit system is different to 31 bit system

[image: 64 bit system is different to 31 bit system]